# How can i get a block of commands to run in a batch command?

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to get a bunch of things to run  in a Batch command build step.

I am trying the following:

```
if %Build_Param% =="Test"
{
  echo "test1"
  echo "test2"
}
```

but it does not work .
How can i get this to run and echo both lines in a  Windows batch command ?

UPDATE:

```
set string1="%Build_Param%"
set string2="Test1"
set string3="Test2"

if %string1% == %string2%
(
 echo "Both the strings are equal Test1"
 echo "Both the strings are Test1A"
)
else if %string1% == %string3%
(
 echo "Both the strings are equal Test2"
 echo "Both the strings are Test2A"
)
```

Comment: Use () instead of {}.

Comment: I have tried , doesnt seem to work , says syntax error. Do you have an example ?

Comment: Also as we have no indication of how the variable named `Build_Param` was defined, or what its value is, it is important to mention that both sides of the `If` comparison strings should be doublequoted. ```If /I "%Build_Param%" == "Test" (```, ```Echo "Test1"```, ```Echo "Test2"```, ```)```.

Comment: I have added code in the question

Comment: The opening parenthesis should be part of the same line as the `if` command. The `else` command must be on the same line as the closing `if` parenthesis, and its opening parenthesis should be part of the same line as it too.

Answer (score 0):

In batch, parentheses are used instead of curly brackets. Also, the opening parenthesis has to go on the same line as the `if` command, so you're locked into K&R style. If you want to use `else`, that has to go on the same line as the previous close parenthesis.

It's worth noting that quotation marks are included in comparisons, so unless `%Build_Param%` includes quotes, you'll want to wrap that in quotes if you want a valid check. Additionally, `echo` does not require quotes.

```
set "string1=%Build_Param%"
set "string2=Test1"
set "string3=Test2"

if "%string1%"=="%string2%" (
    echo Both the strings are equal Test1
    echo Both the strings are Test1A
) else if "%string1%"=="%string3%" (
    echo Both the strings are equal Test2
    echo Both the strings are Test2A
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Windows batch scripting, you need to use the IF statement followed by the condition in parentheses. The condition should not be enclosed in quotes. Additionally, you need to use the ELSE statement to handle the case where the condition is false.

```
IF "%Build_Param%"=="Test" (
    echo "test1"
    echo "test2"
) ELSE (
    echo "Build_Param is not Test"
)
```

Comment: The code you posted doesn't match the description of the solution that you wrote. You put each thing being compared in quotes and didn't wrap the condition in parentheses even though you said the code needed the opposite of that.

Comment: can i also run an exe in the block ?

Comment: @user22147570 - you can do whatever you want in the code block